# Read an attribute of an XmlArray element

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

How do we read an attribute of an XML array element? 
The below code I use to read an attribute of an XML array element which is not working. please let me know an alternate solution to read if avaliable or what i was missing. I saw a lot of samples but unable to identify what i was missing.

Source xml to read is

```
 <RootElement>
  <devices AttNAme="attValue">
   <device>
     <sometag/>
   <device>
   <device>
      <sometag/>
    <device>
 </devices>
<RootElement>
```

The Code i use is

```
[XmlRoot("RootElement")]
public class RootElement
{
[XmlArrayItem("DeviceType", typeof(DeviceTypeSection))]
    [XmlArray("devices")]
    public DeviceTypesSection DeviceTypesInfo { get; set; }

 }

[XmlType("DeviceTypes")]
public class DeviceTypesSection : List<DeviceTypeSection>
{
    [XmlAttribute("AttNAme")]
    public string AttNAme{ get; set; }
}

..and so on
```

Thanks,

Comment: How about matching up "DeviceType" and "DeviceTypes" ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman : Thanks , but I did not understand the logic you said.

Comment: I cannot make them same because i use 'devices' tab attribute to save all devices level info and and for each device info i have separate  set of info to save with more sub tags. But is there any clue what i am possibly missing here?

Comment: Temp fix: Currently resolved this issue using LINQ to XML to directly find those array nodes and reading the attributes of that nodes.        Permamnent fix : welcome. (looking how i can read attributes of arrylist node directly when deserialzing the document at once).

Comment: OK, "make them same" was too simple. But you need full info for mapping types to tags, not clear from your question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman : Thanks for followup . You may assume the xml i have written would be the  document i plan to read. I hope this makes things clear.

Comment: The answer to the same is given at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466142/xmlattribute-not-working-with-xmlarray/12466720#12466720